# How can I change the default email address format type for replies on blackberry?

Tags: email, exchange, smtp, blackberry, bes

Exchange 2007
BES 5.0.x

Hello all,

I'm trying to help a colleague with a technical issue.  I apologize in advance for not having all of the information.  I'm looking for some advice on where to begin troubleshooting...

When users compose new messages on their blackberries, the email address format for these messages is standard SMTP (bob.smith@example.com).  However, when users reply... the email address format for the recipients is Exchange EX (for example: Smith,BobEX/O=EXAMPLE /OU=IT /CN=RECIPIENTS).

Where is the address format preference stored?  We'd like to always use SMTP formatted addresses.

Is this a BES setting? Or an Exchange Address Policy setting?